# How to add modal to tabs in Ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-use-ionic-modal-popovers-and-pass-data-and-receive-response/

Here's what i did.

1) Created a new Page "prd-modal.page"

```
ionic g page prd-modal
```

2) 
then in tab2.module.ts:

```
import { PrdModalPageModule } from '../prd-modal/prd-modal.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    PrdModalPageModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab2Page }]),
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page]
})
```

3) calls modal when marker is clicked

```
addMarker(){
..
        this.map.addMarker(markerOptions).then(marker => {
            marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((data) => {
                console.log("daata"+data);
                alert(data);
                this.openModal();
            });     
        });
}
```

However, when i loaded my app, my whole tab 2 is already on top of tab 2 content(I've a map on tab2). I tried debugging it and my whole tab 2 is replaced by the modal..Meaning my tab 2 is no longer there. Its completely replaced by the modal and its content.

I seriously don't know where I've gone wrong. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issue and this is how you solve it:

1- Remove **import { PrdModalPageModule } from '../prd-modal/prd-modal.module';** from **tab2.module.ts**

2- Still in **tab2.module.ts** add **import { PrdModalPage } from '../prd-modal/prd-modal.page';** to **tab2.module.ts**

3- Still in **tab2.module.ts** add **PrdModalPage** into declarations array

4- In your **tabs router file** add **import { PrdModalPage } from '../prd-modal/prd-modal.page';**

5- Still in your **tabs router file** add

```
{
    path: 'prdModalPage',
    component: PrdModalPage
}
```

to the routes array